# Концепты для Python классов

Tags: python, c++, аннотации, concept

Есть класс, к примеру:

```
class MyClass:
    def foo(self, x: int) -> None:
        print(x)
```

Как можно сделать type hint для параметра, который является "подобным классом", т.е. содержит метод `foo`, принимающий такие же параметры и возвращающий такой же тип.

```
def bar(like_MyClass: typing_shenanigans_for_MyClass_interface) -> None:
    like_MyClass.foo(42)
```

В `bar` должны передаваться классы типа `MyClass` и другие подобные, для других -- варнинг. Другими словами, есть ли у type hints Python функциональность как у C++ concepts?

Comment: Можно создать абстрактный базовый класс и указать в type hint его.

Comment: @nomnoms12 я правильно понимаю, что такое решение медленнее (из-за наследования) обычных аннотаций?

Answer (score 0):

> есть ли у type hints Python функциональность как у C++ concepts?

Нет. `type hints` в `Python` "для людей", они не ограничивают передачу аргумента того или иного типа. Даже написав так:

```
def foo(x: int):
    return x

foo("sr")
```

вы не получите предупреждение.
Можно проверять является ли класс переменной "подходящим":

```
ex_types = (int, float, str)
def foo(x):
    if not isinstance(x, ex_types):
        raise TypeError(f'This function doesn\'t support {type(a)} type')
    return x
```